# Error when building .NET 8 Blazor Hybrid MAUI in GitHub Actions using windows agents

Tags: c#, .net, github-actions, maui

I'm trying to build .NET 8 Blazor Hybrid MAUI App in GitHub Actions. Here is the [repo](https://github.com/fingers10/BlazorHybrid) that I have used.

```yaml
name: build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout the code
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3.4.0

      # Install .NET Core SDK
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
          
      # Install dotnet wasm buildtools workload
      - name: Install .NET WASM Build Tools
        run: dotnet workload install wasm-tools

      # Install dotnet maui buildtools workload
      - name: Install .NET MAUI Build Tools
        run: dotnet workload install maui

      # Restore Dependencies
      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
        
      # Build Project
      - name: Build Solution
        run: dotnet build ./BlazorHybrid.sln --configuration Release --no-restore
```

When I used the above I got the following error:

```
Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(491,5): error NETSDK1112: The runtime pack for Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.win-x64 was not downloaded. Try running a NuGet restore with the RuntimeIdentifier 'win-x64'. [D:\a\BlazorHybrid\BlazorHybrid\MAUI\MAUI.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0]
Error: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.201\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(266,5): error NETSDK1047: Assets file 'D:\a\BlazorHybrid\BlazorHybrid\MAUI\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net8.0-maccatalyst/maccatalyst-arm64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net8.0-maccatalyst' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'maccatalyst-arm64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers. [D:\a\BlazorHybrid\BlazorHybrid\MAUI\MAUI.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-maccatalyst]
```

Here is the complete [run link](https://github.com/fingers10/BlazorHybrid/actions/runs/8000638113/job/21850392273) for the error.

So I tried the following,

1. [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77664585/10851213) from Stackoverflow.. Didn't work.
2. [maui-sample](https://github.com/dotnet/maui-samples/blob/main/8.0/Apps/WeatherTwentyOne/devops/GitHubActions/windowsCI.yml) Didn't work.

Please can you assist me on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some studying, I understood that each project needs to be built separately.

So I have updated the `yml` as shown below. This works.

```
name: build

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build-and-test:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout the code
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3.4.0

      # Install .NET Core SDK
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x
          
      # Install dotnet buildtools workload
      - name: Install .NET Build Tools
        run: dotnet workload install maui macos ios wasm-tools

      # Restore Dependencies
      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
        
      # Build Blazor
      - name: Build Blazor
        run: dotnet build ./Web/Web.csproj --configuration Release --no-restore

      # Build Android
      - name: Build Android
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-android --configuration Release --no-restore

      # Build IOS
      - name: Build IOS
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-ios --configuration Release --no-restore

      # Build Windows
      - name: Build Windows
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0 -p:RuntimeIdentifierOverride=win-x64 --configuration Release

      # Build MacCatalyst
      - name: Build MacCatalyst
        run: dotnet build ./MAUI/MAUI.csproj -f net8.0-maccatalyst --configuration Release
```

Successful build with above `yml`: https://github.com/fingers10/BlazorHybrid/actions/runs/8167144789/job/22327070860

**Source:**

[.NET Conf 2023 session](https://youtu.be/PattkMhmnzE)

[sample GitHub and Azure DevOps build pipelines](https://github.com/Sweekriti91/dotNETConf23DevOps?tab=readme-ov-file)